# Right click on ps1 file > Edit: Is no longer assosiated with ISE (After uninstalling Sapien Powershell studio)

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

After uninstalling powershell studio I have the following issue.

When i right click a ps1 file and than edit i get this error message:

> This file does not have an app associated with it performing this action....

(I have powershell V5 and win 10 1909)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Reg key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ps1`

and set `(Default)` to `Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1`

Open Reg key (create it if it does not exist) `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Edit\Command`

and set `(Default)` to `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe" "%1"`

Restart computer and the edit button in the context menu should work.